# Calculating the feet of head for a single loop cast iron radiator system

Tags: hydronic

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the total equivalent length of a loop with cast iron radiators.  The pipes and fittings are easy to calculate because pipe is calculated linearly, and the fittings are just looked up in a table, but how should the radiators be included in this?  How does one figure out how many feet of head to add to the loop to account for the radiators?

Comment: A quick and simple google search gives : https://runtalnorthamerica.com/commercial_institutional/technical_calculating_pressure.html

Comment: That link is for the new style runtal radiators, as opposed to the old style cast iron radiators.

Comment: But if you understand the theory and the formula (like how to calculate pressure drop using the friction factor) then it is possible to adjust or re-work for any type of radiator or device that causes a pressure loss.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to treat a radiator is to pretend like it is a piece of straight pipe, so if the radiator is 4 feet long it counts as 4 feet of straight pipe.

I got this information when I asked a hydronic heating specialist how one does this calculation.